# Listen to download event in Nexus plugin API

Tags: java, maven, plugins, nexus

I would like to write a Nexus plugin that dinamically patches an artifact.
In other words when a Maven build requests an artifact download, the event should be caught by the Nexus plugin, the artifact should be patched and returned to the caller. No modification should be made to the artifact stored in the server's file system.

I searched the Nexus API plugin documentation and some sample projects, but I found nothing about how to this kind of event (if any hook exists at all).

Does someone has suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: That sounds really weird...What is the purpose of such thing?

Comment: Sounds like an attempt to put a virus into somebody's codebase...

Comment: It is an experiment to put a customized patch into my own code, using my own private artifact repo.

Answer (score 1):

To go about this, you'll need to implement a ContributedHandler, more than likely. You can look at HandlerContributor to see how these are activated. Thanks to magic of Guice and OSGi it should automagickally slide in.